# Terminology in logic theory

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Edit: **I should point out that, I tried searching by myself, but without success. Every time  I thought I got the terminology correct, I tried to use it, but, I didn't get relevant results..**

I'm taking a logic course in my native language, and I'm having trouble finding the same terminology in english. So here are a few questions.

the first expression, can be assigned True or False, is it called an Atom in english too?

$$ p_i $$ 
what would an expression like this be called?
$$
p_i \land (\neg p_j)
$$

what is the term for z called?
$$
z ⊨\alpha
$$
here's a question from my homework:

prove the K "isn't definable".
$$
K = Ass \backslash \{z\}
$$

what I mean mean by "isn't definable", is that there isn't a set like, 
$$
\Sigma = \{\alpha,\beta\,...,\theta\}
$$
that:
$$
M(\Sigma)=K
$$

I hope I explained myself good enough. And thanks for anyone that would help :)

Comment: What is $\text {Ass}$ ? It must be a set of formulas and thus $K = \text {Ass} \setminus \{ z \}$ is the set of formulas obtained from $\text {Ass}$ after "deleting" formula $z$.

Comment: After a few more searches, I think it's called valuation, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, $p_i$ is a [propositional variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_variable) or *atom* (or *atomic formula*): in the context of proposiational logic it represent an "undecomposable" sentence.

2) $p_i ∧ (¬p_j)$ is a *formula* and specifically a [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction).

3) In an expression like $\Gamma \vDash \alpha$, meaning that formula $\alpha$ is [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) of the set $\Gamma$ of formulas, we may call the formulas in $\Gamma$ *premises* or *assumptions*.

But we can have also : $v \vDash \alpha$, where $v$ is a [*valuation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) (also called *truth assignment*), i.e. an assignment of truth values to propositional variables.

A valuation can be uniquely extended to an assignment of truth values to all propositional formulas.

Thus, $v \vDash \alpha$ means that valuation $v$ *satisfies* formula $\alpha$, i.e. that $v$ assigns to $\alpha$ the value TRUE.

I assume that $\text {Ass}$ is the set of all valuations.

Thus, the question about definability of $K = \text {Ass} \setminus \{ z \}$ amounts to :

> find a set $\Sigma = \{ p_i \mid \ldots \}$ of propositional variables, such that $K$ is the set of *models* of $\Sigma$ (call it : $\text {Mod} (\Sigma)$), i.e. the set of valuations that assign to the formulas in $\Sigma$ the value TRUE (i.e. $\text{Mod}(\Sigma) = \{ v \mid v \text { is a valuation and  } v \vDash \sigma \text { for every } \sigma \in \Sigma \}$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, another small question, is there another way to say "isn't definable", or more correct way to say this?

Comment: @Newone12 - it is not clear what "it is definable" means in the context of propositional calculus. Can you give us some more details, please ?

Comment: I'll try to give an example for a "definable" set: for each valuation z, the group: $$ K=\{ z \} $$ is definable by the group: $$ \Sigma = \{p_i | z(p_i)=True\} \bigcup \{\neg p_i | z(p_i)=False\} $$ and the notation for this would be: $$ M(\Sigma)=K $$